# How do I access data in a class stored in a node through queue pointers?

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, queue

In my current assignment I'm having trouble figuring out how I can access this particular piece of data.

To start off, the assignment calls for data to be pulled from a file to simulate a store operating normally. The only thing is, the data being pulled is about the customer. Specifically it's when the customer enters a queue and how long it takes for the cashiers to process their order.

Right now how I have customer data stored in an array of classes.

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
{  
  /* !!!!!IMPORTANT!!!!!  
   * The way this program extracts file data assumes that the file will  
follow a specific format  
   * results will vary heavily based on how the file is set up  
   *   
   * before docking points please make sure that the file follows the format  
   *   
   *  "Number of entries"  
   *  "Customer Number", "Arrival Time", "Service Time"  
   *  "Customer Number", "Arrival Time", "Service Time"  
   *  "Customer Number", "Arrival Time", "Service Time"   
   */

  xfiles >> dataEntry;
  fileData[i].setNumber(dataEntry);
  //inserts a number from the file into the "number" variable in the customer class.
  xfiles >> dataEntry;
  fileData[i].setArrival(dataEntry);
  //inserts a number from the file into the "arrival" variable in the customer class.
  xfiles >> dataEntry;
  fileData[i].setServTime(dataEntry);
  //inserts a number from the file into the "servTime" variable in the customer class.
} 

xfiles.close();
```

It's not included with the code but there is a line that takes in account for entries earlier in the program.

In my next block I have to queue and process customers simultaneously through a period of time. I have an idea how what I should do to queue them but I'm not too sure how I should proceed on processing them. For what I know right now I believe I might want to do a conditional statement to check if a certain customer from the array have been queued or not.

The piece of data I'm currently trying to access would be the arrival time that was stored in the class.

So something like,
fileData[i].returnArrival();

but since that class is stored in a queue I'm not sure how I would be able to access it.

Right now how I have everything queued is

```
for(int x = 0; x < 570; x++)
{
  if(cusTime == x)
  {
     if(scully.isFull() = false)
        scully.enqueue(fileData[cusTime]);
     else if(mulder.isFull() = false)
        mulder.enqueue(fileData[cusTime]);
     else if(skinner.isFull() = false)
        skinner.enqueue(fileData[cusTime]);
     else
        cout << "queues are full, disposing..\n";
  }
  cusTime++;
}
```

At first I thought it would be something like

```
scully.returnFront()->temp->returnClass()->fileData.returnArrival();
```

but I'm unsure about since temp is only a pointer declared within the queue class.

There was another suggestion from a friend of mine who suggested it would probably be something like this instead, but I ended up getting segmentation errors when I ran the code.

```
scully.returnFront()->returnClass().returnArrival();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing it a bit with the professor and TA the cause of the problem was that the return front function was returning a pointer making it more difficult to access the data within the node. A solution was to have the return front function return the Class associated with the data and have the return statement return a pointer that's pointing to the class function that returns the class stored in the node.

so

```
Node *returnFront();
```

was changed to

```
Customer returnFront();
```

changes within the function was

```
return front;
```

to

```
return front->returnClass();
```

these changes made it easier to access the Customer class data from inside the main file. So I was able to instantiate a new place holding variable for the class.

```
Customer scullyTemp;
```

And after that store the data from inside the class that was stored in the node through an assignment statement.

```
scullyTemp = scully.returnFront();
scullyTemp.returnArrival();
```

It might be a little more complicated than it needs to be, but for now it does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be the following:

```
scully.returnFront().returnArrival()
```

Because you enqueue the items from your array. Thus, returnFront() retrieves an item on which your methods should be possible.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home from classes, but would it really work like that? Front is a pointer within the queue class, so I figured it would have to point to something at least.

Comment: if returnFront returns a pointer to the object you should instead use `scully.returnFront()->returnArrival()`